# Grails ConcurrentModificationException in custom eventlistener

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a Grails (2.4.3) application which uses a PersistenceListener to listen on GORM events.

The PersistenceListener works fine.  In the PreUpdate event, it calls a service (injected) which does a findAll on a related object.  Here, I am just gathering values to update a 3rd party system.  The service doesn't change any object value at all including the event.entityObject.

It gets a ConcurrentModificationException after the PreUpdate is run and the instance.save is invoked on the controller.

If I remove/comment the findAll of the related object, the exception goes away.

I suspect this is to do with Hibernate.  Related questions all talk about iterators and using their remove methods. Here I am not removing any values, just trying to get the related objects.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on JDK 8 where even sort is also considered as a modification operation different from JDK 7 ?

This may not be an answer; but I had to write it as an answer since I don't have permission to comment. Please remove this if its not relevant.

Comment: Thanks.  It is JDK 7.  I went back to use GORM events even though it's not a clean solution.